Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity I need to access the method to validate username password coming from another source
I am working on a Blazor project and I had to implement a SOAP service side to it. Long story short aside from normal cookie authentication that comes with the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity module on sample blazor project I also needed a basic authentication for SOAP part. I need to validate user coming from SOAP request.
I have no idea how to do so. Is there a method that I can use on identity side to validate user?

To validate a user for basic authentication in your SOAP service within a Blazor project using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity, you can leverage the SignInManager and UserManager classes to authenticate the user manually.
